# Air Application affected by Computer's Set Date

Tags: apache-flex, date, air, time-trial

I'm working on creating a 30 day free trial of my Air app.

When the 30 day trial begins the current date is stored in the local encrypted database. Then the date is checked against the current date if the difference is 30 days or more the application denies access and the users is prompted to purchase a license.

It seemed I had have everything working fine but I just ran into a problem.

I changed the date on my machine which made my Air app think this was the current date, allowing the 30 day trail to still be active.

I'm wondering what the workaround might be to fix this? Is it possible for Air to get the current date not based on the computers set date?

Comment: I'd like to avoid this if possible. My application is desktop based, and only requires an internet connection for activation and application updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you application has logging to a file system, preferably a sign-on logging event, write a file or update a file.

Prior to this writing step, do a check in that directory to see if any of those files are dated in the future. If they are, the user has rolled back their system. Flag it.

Try not to use sharedObject cause that I might get blowaway. Alternatively you can update a table in SQLite or whatever persistence mechanism you are implementing in your app.